# Getting HTTP Error 403: SSL is required when trying to install virtualenvwrapper-powershell

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to follow [this](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows) tutorial and I'm at the virtualenv+virtualenvwrapper step. Running `pip install virtualenv` works fine. However, when I try `pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell` I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\zakst\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-ekeoqg\\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\zakst\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-ekeoqg\\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\zakst\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ekeoqg\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: c:\users\zakst\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ekeoqg\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\
Complete output (24 lines):
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.10.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zakst\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ekeoqg\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What I've tried:

1. Updating pip
2. Restarting powershell/PC
3. Running `pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/` (gives the same error as above)
4. Using the `--trusted-host` command for pypi.org, files.pythonhosted.org, and pypi.python.org when trying to install the package (returns the same error as above).
5. adding the above URLs as trusted hosts in pip.ini (returns the same error as above).
6. Downloading virtualenvwrapper-powershell directly from [here](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/) (and also tried downloading version 2.7.1 of it) and running setup.py. Still got the same 403 error.
7. Doing all of the above on a different computer, also running Windows 10, with a clean install and on a different network.

I am not sure what I can do to fix this since virtually every solution to this issue I've come across involves doing one of the above things, none of which have worked for me. Using Python 2.7.17 on Windows 10.

Comment: What version of Windows? What version of Python?

Comment: @phd Windows 10 and Python 2.7.17.